# Reading from Hive Table (Parque) and Storing as Text File

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform

I have read data from Hive Table sotred as Parquet file into DF. After applying some transformations to DataFrame, I want to save back as TextFile on HDFS.

I am using following piece of code. But, I am facing following two issues:

```
val input_data = spark.sql("select * from db.table1")
input_data.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("delimiter","\u00A1").csv("/bigdatahdfs/landing/demo.txt")
```

1. File is written with garbage characters : (Viewing file on HDFS)

   [image: Viewing file on HDFS]
2. Also, can I control FileName as its written into Directory with some random name.

   [image]

Comment: What is the output of `input_data.show(10)`? What happened when you save the file using the default delimiter?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Are you required to use Spark? You could create a Hive table that's stored as text then insert overwrite into that, and no, you can't control the filename in HDFS for the result, only the directory

Comment: @cricket_007 as I mentioned I am doing other processing and I am writing final df on HDFS... However I resolved this by making compression as None. Can you help on second question.. it's creating file with name part001.... Can I create file with preferred name.

Comment: I already answered that at the end of the comment